# Redirecting control from one controller to another in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to redirect control from one controller to another, but it is not happening. I went through previous stackoverflow questions but their solutions are not working in my case.

My Controller is

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping( "/rest/auth" )
public class UnprotectedController extends AbstractController {

@Autowired
private UserServices userService;

@Autowired
private RequesterService requesterService;


@RequestMapping(value = "/login",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/login");
}
}
```

In `Postman` If I hit `http://localhost:8090/login` I am getting valid response. But if I hit `http://localhost:8090/rest/auth/login`, I am getting error as

```
{
"timestamp": 1504340884618,
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "No message available",
"path": "/login"
```

}

It seems control is not redirecting to the `redirect url` specified. Why is this happening?

`http://localhost:8090/login` is the path where `spring security` verifies user's credentials and creates `Security Context`

Comment: wasnt this relevant to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880772/spring-boot-redirect-to-a-different-controller-method

Comment: Thats what I did. But it is not working

Comment: which spring security version you are using?

Comment: It makes `POST` request....So is there no hack to achieve this?

Comment: If Postman makes `POST /login`, then I was wrong and it should work. Show your Spring Security configuration, maybe there is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you can do this on another way. By using this HttpServletResponse you are having as an argument.

```
response.sendRedirect("/login");
```

However, it throws two types exceptions, so a try/catch would have to go as well.

And the problem you are having that you are using the @RestController annotation on your controller that gives all methods a @ResponseBody annotation and I think you cannot return a ModelAndView as a response body.

Try returning a String with something like

```
return "redirect:/login"
```

or

```
return "forward:/login";
```

Comment: I tried, But it is saying
   ` {
    "timestamp": 1504522158996,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/login"
    }`

Comment: Check 2 things.When your app starts up, look in the logs all the mappings it shows. You should find your controller mappings there. If they are not, they are not getting picked up by scanning. Also, try the routes. Maybe you need to add an apsolute mapping like "http://localhost:8080/login"